# Permissions/Roles in GraphQL

Tags: roles, graphql, security-roles, graphiql

Is it possible to show that some collections can be accessed only by user which has same permissions/roles?

For example how it is in https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create

```
Expected scopes:
channels:write read
```

Answer (score 0):

> The concept of access permissions exists at the layer of business
>   logic and is not intrinsic to GraphQL itself. I think your best bet
>   here may be documenting any constraints that in description fields in
>   the schema, where they will then be shown in the GraphiQL
>   documentation explorer.

https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/issues/564